# upload a file to a server through a POST request

Tags: r

In R, I would like to upload a file to a server through a POST request. I use RCurl package, but I am ready to use another package if it could solve the problem.

The code I have so far is the following, but it does not work, as explained in the comments at the end of the code:

```
library("RCurl")

uri <- "https://www.xxx.com/yyy.php?auth=2"
file.name <- "D:\\temp_pic_2013-11-09_17_14_41.png"
result1 <- postForm(uri, theFile = fileUpload(filename = file.name, contentType="image/png"), .opts = list(ssl.verifypeer = FALSE))

# result1 contains the following whereas it should contain the url of the uploaded pic:
# [1] "Error processing request"
# attr(,"Content-Type")
# 
# "text/html"
```

Note: I succeeded in uploading files on the same server with a Java code, so the problem is very probably within my R code and not on the server side.

Thanks in advance for your help,

Nicolas

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

theFile = fileUpload(...) should be replaced by file= fileUpload(...)

The solution was on the configuration of the server side.

Nicolas